# How to run these two rows on one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this structure

```
Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  user_id int(11)         No          None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 2  amount  decimal(16,8)   No          None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 3  aff int(11)             No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 4  jackpot int(11)         No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 5  paidout int(11)         No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 6  type    int(11)         No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 7  created timestamp       No   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
```

I am trying this 2 rows on the same query without success:

```
UPDATE `trans` where paidout=1 GROUP BY user_id
UPDATE `trans`where paidout=0 GROUP BY user_id
```

also just to view not to update would be fine

like this

```
SELECT * FROM  `trans` where paidout=1 GROUP BY user_id
SELECT * FROM  `trans` where paidout=0 GROUP BY user_id
```

I need to run these 2 rows on the same query

I need to group  the table rows by user_id  but the the same user_id has paidout=1 in some rows and paidout=0 in some other rows

so i want to group by user_id where paidout=1 and GROUP BY user_id where paidout=0

so i will get 2 rows for each user_id

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: For the `Update` query, You need to actually set something. An example would be `UPDATE trans set paidout=0 WHERE paidout=1`

As Gordon pointed out, what is your desired result?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve in either request. An `UPDATE` with a `GROUP BY` doesn't mean anything, and of course you need to set something. For the `SELECT`, you can `GROUP BY user_id,paidout`, but you need to decide what you want to show for each line (count? sum? min? max?...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guessing what you want from the little you gave us:

```
SELECT user_id,paidout,count(*),sum(amount) FROM trans GROUP BY user_id,paidout
```

Comment: You're definitely not specific enough as to what you want to achieve. If you want to dump the whole table, it's just: `SELECT * FROM table`...

Comment: I am saying that your answer is correct , but i want to keep the table structure in the results i get from the query, so can you edit the code above

Comment: With the information you provided, it's not possible. If you do a `GROUP BY`, that means several lines are grouped together in the output, and you need to decide how you display each "group". You can display counts, sums, averages, the smallest or largest value, or any combination thereof. You need to decide what you want to get before anyone can write the request.

Comment: i want to sum the amounts

Comment: Well, that's what the query given above does (it also counts the number of lines in each group, but you can remove that bit if you don't want it).

Comment: I need the output to have the same structure like the table trans , this is what i am trying to say , maybe i am not being able to explain it correctly

Comment: @user38935 What do you mean preserve the table structure? Can you post an example of what you want the result to look like? I don't see how the table's structure can be preserved when you use a `Group By` query..

Comment: user_id  amount aff jackpot paidout type created

Comment: As there is a group by, there are (probably) several lines in each group. How do I combine the several lines? What should be the value of "type" or "created" for these several lines?

Comment: "aff", "type" and "jackpot" value can be 0 "created" value can be whatever it is not important

Comment: `SELECT user_id,sum(amount) as amount,0 as aff,0 as jackpot,paidout,0 as type,0 as created FROM trans GROUP BY user_id,paidout`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply view all records which have Paidout=0 and Paidout=1, you need to do :

```
SELECT * from `trans` WHERE paidout = 1
```

or

```
SELECT * from `trans` WHERE paidout = 0
```

or (If you want both)

```
SELECT * from `trans` WHERE paidout = 1 OR paidout = 0
```

A `Group By` clause is only needed if you want to use an aggregate function (Sum, Average, Max, Min, etc).

If you DO want a to run an Aggregate function(For example, if you want the number of records with `paidout` = 1 and 0), then you will do :

```
SELECT paidout, count(paidout) FROM `trans` GROUP BY paidout
```

I hope this has solved your problem, if not, please do reply with more details and I will update this answer!

Note : These are only the most basic ways to run these queries, you can further tweak and optimize them for your own need, but that is beyond the scope of this answer!